# How to rename column names using a pattern of names in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 7000+ columns and I want to assign names to them in a pattern such as G1, G2, G3....
It is not possible by simply using colnames or rename functions.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is the full pattern for naming the columns?

Comment: If you merely want to rename the data in order, just `colnames(df) <- paste0('G', 1:ncol(df))`